# Combining values in an array in Python

Tags: python

I have an array like so: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'].

I've been trying to figure out how to make it like so: ['AB', 'CD', 'E']

I'm not sure where to start. Thanks in advance!

Comment: try using `for n in range(0,len(array)): newarray[n//2] += array[n]`

Comment: [The `grouper` recipe from the `itertools` documentation provides a decent solution](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Comment: @Iain Shelvington I think that we should answer rather than just minusing question. Maybe he/she just couldn't clear where to find

Answer (score 2):

main.py

```py
a = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
b = [i + j for i, j in zip(a[:-1:2], a[1::2])]
if len(a) % 2 == 1:
  b.append(a[-1])
print(b)
```

result

```
$ python main.py
['AB', 'CD', 'E']
```

Comment: Thank you I figured it out the question. Fixed and updated.

Comment: Thank you for check. fixed but your answer is much better for reading and computational efficiency

Comment: You could make yours perhaps a bit prettier with `zip(a[::2], a[1::2] + [''])`, although it's less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [''.join(a[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(a), 2)]
['AB', 'CD', 'E']
```

or (as I love iterators)

```
>>> it = iter(a)
>>> [s + next(it, '') for s in it]
['AB', 'CD', 'E']
```

Comment: Wow, Thanks a ton! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easier way is to iterate through the array and concatenate the chars, it works if you have an array with even length, so you could add a check and append the last element in case of odd length.

```
array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

array2 = [f"{array[i]}{array[i+1]}" for i in range(0, len(array)-1, 2)]

if len(array)%2!=0:
    array2.append(array[-1])

print(array2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. This is  very bare answer but should work.

```
my_array =  ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

def combine_array(my_array):
    mixed_array = []
    start_new = True
    for item in my_array:
        if start_new:
            mixed_array.append(item)
            start_new = False
        else:
            mixed_array[-1] = mixed_array[-1] + item
            start_new = True
    return mixed_array


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        print(combine_array(my_array))
    except Exception as err:
        print(err)
```

Comment: Can someone explain  why I got minus ?! This answer is tested and its working.

Comment: Maybe someone didn't like the amount of code. I don't like that, either, but it's correct, efficient and simple, so I countervoted.

Answer (score -1):

```
startArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
currentIndex = 0
finishArray = ['']
for x in startArray:
    if len(finishArray[currentIndex]) == 2:
        currentIndex += 1
        finishArray.insert(currentIndex,x)
    else: 
        finishArray[currentIndex] += x
print(finishArray)
```